# How to make Windows XP computer discoverable to a Mac?

Tags: windows-xp, networking, osx-lion

I'm really not sure whether this is a Mac question or a PC question, so I will [cross-post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/windows-xp-server-needs-reboot-to-be-discoverable-with-os-x-lion) to both SE sites.

I'm running a Windows Workgroup with a number of Macs and PCs on the LAN. All the PCs can access our Windows XP file share (just another computer with sharing turned on - NOT a server per se), but the Macs don't see the fileshare computer unless we manually type in the smb:// address.

Connection isn't actually the problem. It's the discoverability of the Windows shared drives that's the issue. Interestingly, our NAS drives are perfectly discoverable; only the Windows XP computer is not discuverable unless it's turned on AFTER the Macs are booted. If the Windows XP PC was left on and the Mac was rebooted in the meantime, then I have to cycle the Windows PC in order for it to become discoverable under the Networks icon.

What do I have to do to allow the XP computer to be discoverable at all times? Is there some Samba service that should be running on the PC? Currently neither Bonjour nor Samba are running.

Comment: FYI, OS X questions *are* on-topic here.  (They are also on topic at apple.SE, of course.)

Comment: Here is the link to the Ask Different cross-post: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52946/windows-xp-server-needs-reboot-to-be-discoverable-with-os-x-lion.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this with a Mac and XP but I have with Linux to Windows 7.

In your smb.conf, add the line:

browsable=yes

See the last post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=65921

Comment: Interesting, but that seems a very linux/unix-specific answer. I'm not aware of any smb.conf file on Windows, and it's a Windows machine that needs to be discoverable.